# Codrops Horizontal Slide Out Menu - Show submenu on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project based on one of the Codrops blueprints: http://l3s11023.zeus03.de/test/

I want to have the first submenu 'Lovely Spirits' already open when the page loads. I tried to do this with jQuery $( document ).ready(function()  and a trigger event but without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: did you include jQuery to your site? (there is no jquery yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with a part of your code and an example how you could trigger the click in

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Make sure you include jQuery

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.cbp-hsmenu').children('li').children('a').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next('ul').css('display','block');
    });

    /* HERE IS the interesting part*/
    /* Trigger click on that function opening your sub-nav */
    $('#gesu').trigger('click');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zms3T/

(Your question is not good. Next time please try to show only that part of code which is needed)

---

> **UPDATE THE ANSWER AFTER LOTS of trying on your site**

---

The Code above was just an example of how you could try it. I was sure you trigger the function to open that navigation. However, replace the document ready with this: That will do what you where looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elemHeight = $('.cbp-hsmenu li:first-child ul').height()
    $('.cbp-hsmenubg').css('height', elemHeight+'px');
    $('.cbp-hsmenu li:first-child').addClass('cbp-hsitem-open');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I implemented the code you provided but it is still not working. The on click function doesn't let the submenu appear.

Comment: and soory abou the question. I'm not sure about the part of code that is needed since I'm not sure where the problem is/why your solution is not working.